# Convert lowercase to uppercase URLs using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to convert `example.com/para1/para2` to `example.com/PARA1/PARA2`. I am using shared hosting so can use htaccess only for rewriting. I found **below htaccess code to convert upper to lower** and I tried using it by replacing all lower to upper and upper to lower but my bad luck, id did not work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If there are caps, set HASCAPS to true and skip next rule
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [E=HASCAPS:TRUE,S=1]

# Skip this entire section if no uppercase letters in requested URL
RewriteRule ![A-Z] - [S=28]

# Replace single occurance of CAP with cap, then process next Rule.
RewriteRule ^([^A]*)A(.*)$ $1a$2
RewriteRule ^([^B]*)B(.*)$ $1b$2
RewriteRule ^([^C]*)C(.*)$ $1c$2
RewriteRule ^([^D]*)D(.*)$ $1d$2
RewriteRule ^([^E]*)E(.*)$ $1e$2
RewriteRule ^([^F]*)F(.*)$ $1f$2
RewriteRule ^([^G]*)G(.*)$ $1g$2
RewriteRule ^([^H]*)H(.*)$ $1h$2
RewriteRule ^([^I]*)I(.*)$ $1i$2
RewriteRule ^([^J]*)J(.*)$ $1j$2
RewriteRule ^([^K]*)K(.*)$ $1k$2
RewriteRule ^([^L]*)L(.*)$ $1l$2
RewriteRule ^([^M]*)M(.*)$ $1m$2
RewriteRule ^([^N]*)N(.*)$ $1n$2
RewriteRule ^([^O]*)O(.*)$ $1o$2
RewriteRule ^([^P]*)P(.*)$ $1p$2
RewriteRule ^([^Q]*)Q(.*)$ $1q$2
RewriteRule ^([^R]*)R(.*)$ $1r$2
RewriteRule ^([^S]*)S(.*)$ $1s$2
RewriteRule ^([^T]*)T(.*)$ $1t$2
RewriteRule ^([^U]*)U(.*)$ $1u$2
RewriteRule ^([^V]*)V(.*)$ $1v$2
RewriteRule ^([^W]*)W(.*)$ $1w$2
RewriteRule ^([^X]*)X(.*)$ $1x$2
RewriteRule ^([^Y]*)Y(.*)$ $1y$2
RewriteRule ^([^Z]*)Z(.*)$ $1z$2

# If there are any uppercase letters, restart at very first RewriteRule in file.
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [N]

RewriteCond %{ENV:HASCAPS} TRUE
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Will really appreciate your kind answers.

Comment: Should work as per existing examples. Are you sure your htaccess is executed (allowed in your server config) and `mod_rewrite` is enabled (also in server config) ? Nevertheless, I suggest no to use `mod_rewrite` for that purpose since it's slow. You should do it from a server script (php for instance)

Comment: Above example is working for upper to lower case but I am looking for lower to upper conversion. Yes, I can run other rewrite rules in htaccess. Sure, I will try with php but I think it would be also helpful for other developers because I did not find such nice htaccess code for lowercase to uppercase.

Comment: From your code, having the opposite version `lower -> upper` is trivial. All you have to do is to apply the reversed logic. See my answer below. Still, I'm surprised your try didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translating `upper -> lower` to `lower -> upper` is trivial since you already have the first working. All you have to do is to apply the reversed logic

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If there are lowers, set HASLOWERS to true and skip next rule
RewriteRule [a-z] - [E=HASLOWERS:TRUE,S=1]

# Skip this entire section if no lowercase letters in requested URL
RewriteRule ![a-z] - [S=28]

# Replace single occurance of lower with LOWER, then process next Rule.
RewriteRule ^([^a]*)a(.*)$ $1A$2
RewriteRule ^([^b]*)b(.*)$ $1B$2
RewriteRule ^([^c]*)c(.*)$ $1C$2
RewriteRule ^([^d]*)d(.*)$ $1D$2
RewriteRule ^([^e]*)e(.*)$ $1E$2
RewriteRule ^([^f]*)f(.*)$ $1F$2
RewriteRule ^([^g]*)g(.*)$ $1G$2
RewriteRule ^([^h]*)h(.*)$ $1H$2
RewriteRule ^([^i]*)i(.*)$ $1I$2
RewriteRule ^([^j]*)j(.*)$ $1J$2
RewriteRule ^([^k]*)k(.*)$ $1K$2
RewriteRule ^([^l]*)l(.*)$ $1L$2
RewriteRule ^([^m]*)m(.*)$ $1M$2
RewriteRule ^([^n]*)n(.*)$ $1N$2
RewriteRule ^([^o]*)o(.*)$ $1O$2
RewriteRule ^([^p]*)p(.*)$ $1P$2
RewriteRule ^([^q]*)q(.*)$ $1Q$2
RewriteRule ^([^r]*)r(.*)$ $1R$2
RewriteRule ^([^s]*)s(.*)$ $1S$2
RewriteRule ^([^t]*)t(.*)$ $1T$2
RewriteRule ^([^u]*)u(.*)$ $1U$2
RewriteRule ^([^v]*)v(.*)$ $1V$2
RewriteRule ^([^w]*)w(.*)$ $1W$2
RewriteRule ^([^x]*)x(.*)$ $1X$2
RewriteRule ^([^y]*)y(.*)$ $1Y$2
RewriteRule ^([^z]*)z(.*)$ $1Z$2

# If there are any lowercase letters, restart at very first RewriteRule in file.
RewriteRule [a-z] - [N]

RewriteCond %{ENV:HASLOWERS} TRUE
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and efforts Justin. Yes you are right this code is working, mine was clashing with existing rules. Anyways I found it really slow and used the following php code instead:
<pre>if(preg_match('/[a-z]/', $slug)){
 $slug = mb_convert_case($slug , MB_CASE_UPPER, "UTF-8");
 Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
 Header( "Location: ".$site_url."/".$slug);
}</pre>

Comment: Yes, it's a better option to do so